Does convergence of gradient to zero imply convergence to optimal value?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ convex function that has a minimal value $f^\star = \inf_{\mathbb{R}^n} f$. Assume also that $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous.
Let $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$f(x_k)-f^\star \xrightarrow[k\to+\infty]{} C \quad \text{ and }\quad \Vert \nabla f(x_k)\Vert\xrightarrow[k\to+\infty]{} 0,$$
where $C\geq 0$.
Question: can we prove (or disprove) that necessarily $C=0$?
Attempts:

A sufficient condition is that $x_k$ remains bounded. Then $(x_k)_k$ has an accumulation point $\bar{x}$, which is a critical point, so $f(\bar{x})-f^\star = 0$, and by uniqueness of the limit we get the result.

If $f$ has the Łojasiewicz property or is strongly convex, we can upper bound $f(x_k)-f^\star$ by $\Vert \nabla f(x_k)\Vert$ (up to constants and exponents) and again deduce that $C=0$.


So if a counter-example exists it must involve an unbounded sequence $(x_k)_k$ and a convex function that becomes very flat (i.e. does not have the Łojasiewicz property).
NB: It might be easier to prove in the case where $f$ has at least one minimizer.
Edit: Actually the sufficient condition 1. can be relaxed. If $(x_k)_k$ has a bounded sub-sequence then there exists an accumulation point and we can apply the same reasoning. So the only remaining case is that where $\Vert x_k\Vert\xrightarrow[k\to+\infty]{}+\infty$.

The statement is only true if $(x_k)_k$ admits a bounded sub-sequence. We need distinguish two cases based on this:

If $(x_k)_k$ has a bounded sub-sequence then it has an accumulation point $\bar{x}$. By continuity of the gradient $\nabla f(\bar{x})=0$ so $f(\bar{x})=f^\star$ and the claim is true.

If on the contrary $\Vert x_k\Vert\to+\infty$, then we can construct a counter-example (originally stated here). For $x>0, y\in\mathbb{R}$, define
$$g(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{x},\text{ then, } \nabla g(x,y) = (-\frac{y^2}{x^2},\frac{2y}{x}),\text{ and, } \lVert\nabla g(x,y)\rVert^2 = \frac{y^4}{x^4} + 4 \frac{y^2}{x^2}.$$


Now take $C>0$, and consider every $(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y)=C$. This is every $(x,y)$ such that $y^2=Cx$. For these $(x,y)$, we have $\lVert\nabla g(x,y)\rVert^2 = \frac{C^2}{x^2} + 4 \frac{C}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{} 0$, but by definition $g(x,y)=C>0$.

Your function is not convex

From the fact that $f$ is convex and by Cauchy-Swartz, we have
$$ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, f(x) - f(y) \leq \langle \nabla f(x), x-y\rangle \leq \lVert \nabla f(x) \rVert \lVert x-y\rVert.$$
In particular, this holds for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all the $x_k$.
Assumption: $f$ has at least one minimizer, i.e., there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $f(x^*) = f^* = \inf_{\mathbb{R}^n}f$.
Then taking $y = x^*$ in the previous equation leads to
$$ 0 \leq f(x_k) - f^* = f(x_k) - f(x^*) \leq \lVert \nabla f(x_k) \rVert \lVert x_k-x^*\rVert \to 0.$$
It follows that if you have such a sequence and $f$ has at least one minimizer, then you necessarily have that $C = 0$.
I hope it can be helpful, don't hesitate if I misunderstood your question or if some parts of the proof are incorrect.
Erratum: some conditions should be imposed on $\lVert x_k - x^*\rVert$ to conclude

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, to deduce that the right-hand side goes to zero you need furthermore $(x_k)$ to be bounded, otherwise you may have $x_k-x^\star$ that goes to $+\infty$ faster than $\nabla f(x_k)$ goes to zero.

Yes you're right, I just realized that, thanks.

Maybe you can place yourself at a rank N such that $\lvert f(x_k) - f^\rvert$ is smaller than $C+1$ and as $f(x_k)-f^ \geq \frac{L}{2}\lVert x_k - x^* \rVert$ (sublevel sets of $f$ are bounded because f is cvx and L-smooth), $\lVert x_k-x^*\rVert$ will be bounded.

@AmbroiseOdonnat cvx and L-smooth does not imply that sublevel sets are bounded (take f(x)= 0 for negative x and x² otherwise)

Thanks you’re right, it would need strong cvx.
