Does approximately null gradient imply approximately global minimum for convex functions?
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ be a non-negative and differentiable convex function which vanishes in a non-empty convex set $\Omega$ -- possibly unbounded. Usually, when one approximately minimizes $f$ by quasi-Newton methods, it is obtained a sequence of points $\{x^{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ so that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|\nabla f (x^{k})\| = 0.$ However, it does not seem obvious that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f (x^{k}) = 0$. Consequently, there might be a possibility of distancing from the solution set when searching for critical points of convex functions, which seems odd. So here comes the question:

For a non-negative and differentiable convex function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ which vanishes in a non-empty convex set $\Omega$, does $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|\nabla f (x^{k})\| = 0 \implies \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f (x^{k}) = 0?$$


This question was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4896541/does-convergence-of-gradient-to-zero-imply-convergence-to-optimal-value?rq=1. However, the accepted answer does not provide an unconstrained convex function with the property I and he wanted.

This question was answerd here; https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483415/does-approximately-null-gradient-imply-approximately-global-minimum-for-convex-f
